# Private Key Signing in C# and Public Key Verifying in Java and Swift

Tags: rsa, public-key, signature

I create this question from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61392586/validating-rsa-signature-from-c-sharp-in-java?noredirect=1#comment135114435_61392586).
I am working on a project with C# backend and mobile apps using Java and Swift.
I found this documentation to use [RSACryptoServiceProvider.SignData](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.rsacryptoserviceprovider.signdata?view=net-7.0) method to sign using private key.
But I don't have idea on how to verify and decrypt it on Java and Swift.
From my understanding, it's signed using Private key and then it needs public key to be verified on Java and Swift.
Can someone please help me to understand how I can do this?
Thanks in advance.